# How to understand JSON rfc7159 String and Character Issues

Tags: c#, json

Now I am using C # to implement a JSON serialization tool. The standard I refer to is [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159). I don't understand the content of item 8(String and Character Issues) in this document.

---

```
8.  String and Character Issues

8.1.  Character Encoding

   JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  The default
   encoding is UTF-8, and JSON texts that are encoded in UTF-8 are
   interoperable in the sense that they will be read successfully by the
   maximum number of implementations; there are many implementations
   that cannot successfully read texts in other encodings (such as
   UTF-16 and UTF-32).

   Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark to the beginning of a
   JSON text.  In the interests of interoperability, implementations
   that parse JSON texts MAY ignore the presence of a byte order mark
   rather than treating it as an error.

8.2.  Unicode Characters

   When all the strings represented in a JSON text are composed entirely
   of Unicode characters [UNICODE] (however escaped), then that JSON
   text is interoperable in the sense that all software implementations
   that parse it will agree on the contents of names and of string
   values in objects and arrays.

   However, the ABNF in this specification allows member names and
   string values to contain bit sequences that cannot encode Unicode
   characters; for example, "\uDEAD" (a single unpaired UTF-16
   surrogate).  Instances of this have been observed, for example, when
   a library truncates a UTF-16 string without checking whether the
   truncation split a surrogate pair.  The behavior of software that
   receives JSON texts containing such values is unpredictable; for
   example, implementations might return different values for the length
   of a string value or even suffer fatal runtime exceptions.

8.3.  String Comparison

   Software implementations are typically required to test names of
   object members for equality.  Implementations that transform the
   textual representation into sequences of Unicode code units and then
   perform the comparison numerically, code unit by code unit, are
   interoperable in the sense that implementations will agree in all
   cases on equality or inequality of two strings.  For example,
   implementations that compare strings with escaped characters
   unconverted may incorrectly find that "a\\b" and "a\u005Cb" are not
   equal.
```

The JSON serialization tool I've built is very simple. It can turn objects into strings or strings into objects.
I only exposed 2 APIs

```
public string SerializeToJson(object obj);
public object DeserializeToObj(string json);
```

For serialization, I'm only responsible for generating a string (utf16), and I don't care what binary you encode it into.

For deserialization, at the code level, I accept only one string (I don't care where the string is read from), and I read every char of the string ,Throw an error if the format is incorrect

So I don't understand Json RFC 7159 8.1, 8.2 very well. Why does it appear in the JSON standard?

For a C# JSON serialization tool, should I consider it? If I get it wrong, can you tell me what it means or give me a scenario?

For 8.3, when serialized, I will change it into `\\\\` for `\\` and `\\u005c` for `\u005c`.In deserialization, I read their codes unit for comparison, so `\\` and `\u005c` are certainly the same, so what does 8.3 mean? Is it for serialization or deserialization? Is my understanding correct?
Or does it require me, when serializing, whether `\\` or `\u005c`, to eventually output the same(such as `\\u005c`)?

Comment: An input string comprised of ``\`` `u` `0` `0` `5` `c` (in that order) can have different escaping for any of the 6 characters in that string. Decoders are required to handle all possibilities correctly, and encoders are not required to settle on any particular form -- in particular, you don't have to roundtrip. A string comprised of ``\`` ``\`` likewise has six forms (escaping ``\`` as either ``\\`` or `\u005c` or `\u005C`). Section 7 is more relevant than section 8 here. Keep in mind the *three* layers: character -> JSON character (escaped or not) -> code points of encoded characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the serialization in two steps. First to `String` and then UTF-8 bytes. UTF-8 is required for interchangeable JSON documents ([RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), which obsoletes RFC 7159).

The only escapes you need are inside JSON strings.

> The characters that MUST be escaped:

- quotation mark,
- reverse solidus,
- and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F)

You can choose the manner of escaping quotation mark, reverse solidus, solidus, backspace, formfeed, newline, carriage return and horizontal tab upon serialization.

[www.json.org](http://www.json.org/) has a very appealing "railroad diagram" illustrating this.

(ASCII has nothing to do with anything here.)